# css problem with ie?

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

### CSS

```
.help {
    background: url("/images/info.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    text-indent: -100px;
}
```

### HTML

1)

```
<label for="test_1">City Name Sub
   <span title="City Name Sub" class="help">&nbsp;</span>
</label>
```

2)

```
<label for="test_2">SMMMC 
   <span title="SMMC Sub" class="help">&nbsp;</span>
</label>
```

First lable shows proper image with text. But for the second label getting cropped image from the top in IE.
Any Idea ? Any Solution ?

Comment: could you put it in fiddle or something?

Comment: @krunal shah - see http://jsfiddle.net/  It allows you to try out and test small chunks of CSS/JS/HTML code in a controlled environment, and save those tests to share with others so you can demonstrate your issue.

Comment: @krunal shah - also, please specify which version(s) of IE you're seeing the problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.help {
    background: url("/images/info.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    text-indent: -100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have added display: inline-block to my css class and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your Image looks like, but would this help you ?

CSS ( **edited background and text-indent properties** )

```
.help {
    background: url("/images/info.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="test_1" class="help" title="City Name Sub">City Name Sub</label>
```

Comment: How this will help? Can you explain it please?

Comment: @krunal I don't know how your image looks like. But I'm thinking that using inline elements inside inline elements, just to show a background is leaving more room for Browser interpretation. If it suits your needs - again i can't see how you want it to look - you can have the background on the label itself, and just use *padding-right* to place the image to the right of the text